# Routing Problems in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, router

I am running into trouble with pages not displaying. I think it has to do with my routing. I am just starting to learn this. Thank you in advance. Here is a link to GitHub

https://github.com/PietroSerra/order-login-master2

Answer (score 0):

The link is broken. Is the repo private?